# Why this method is causing out of memory if it is called 150 times

Tags: php

I have this method

```
function updateSessionVariable($objectId, $id, $file){
    $fileName = basename($file);
    // create the mapping for object ID to Doc info such as url
    $format1 = array ($objectId  => array("id" => $id, "file" => $file));
    $_SESSION["objIdtoDoc"] = $_SESSION["objIdtoDoc"] + $format1;

    // now create the mapping for section ID to Object Id
    if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id])){
        $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] =  $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id]+ array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
    }else{
        $format2 = array($id => array(array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName)));
        $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"] = $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"] + $format2;
    }
}
```

which essentially creates 2 different sessions variables.

- `objIdtoDoc` is basically a one to one mapping where `objId` is the key and the value is `(id,file)`
- `sectionIdToObjId` is one to many mapping where `id` is the key and the value is an array of `(objId, filename)`.

I am only calling this method 158 times (meaning  adding 158 rows to each session variable) and it is resulting in php out of memory (over 128M). This can't be right. I have a feeling that I am duplicating data in this method or doing things wrong in this method

Can you please advise?
Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for all the comments, I was able to point the issue where it seems there is a recursive operation going on in the sectionIdToObjId.

What I am trying to achieve is something like that for this variable sectionIdToObjId ( which is in the second part of the method)

```
[id1]=> {("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName)}
[id2]=> {("objId" => $objectId1, "fileName" => $fileName1)
         ,("objId" => $objectId2, "fileName" => $fileName2)}
```

and so on. It keeps updating the array with every call to the method. Apperently wht I had above was messing things up

Comment: Use [xdebug and profile](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) the function call to see where the memory is going. But yes essentially arrays are by copy, not by reference. so `$format1` = file and `$_SESSION["objIdtoDoc"]` = file.

Comment: why are you storing so much data in a session?

Comment: what if you call it `149` times does that work better?

Comment: what is the error you get, the over byte amount is it small or large?  If it's small that can indicate infinite recursion.  How do you know you are calling this `158` times.  It's probably better to build your data outside of the session then when it's built add it to the session, this would avoid all the session save calls between iterations.  Every time you do `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"] = ` your either saving data in the session file ( IO bound ) or in a custom way if you changed the default data but still likely IO bound.  So you are actually making over 300 session saves and reads.

Comment: @fyrye, isn't format a local variable that gets cleared at the end of the method?

Comment: @rtfm, it is only 158 rows of strings, that's not alot. This is extracted from database that is needed through out the sessions.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, all the code gets executed with 150. The error I get is when I return from server to client. But  I don't see this issue if I don't call this method at all

Comment: Are you outputting this huge array to the browser?  I would say avoid doing that, as the browser may not handle a large data dump without flushing (streaming)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: I got this "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes) in Unknown on line 0" on 128M . I increased memory to 256M and  I still got the error.  I am calling it 158 because it is based on the number of records from the database ( and  I added a counter to the looping code that is calling this method). So you suggest  I do the building in another variable and then copy that variable to session?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix No, this data is staored in the session for subsequent server calls only. I am outputing a small JSON array of 10 strings to browser at the end of everything

Comment: So you are not outputinig it at all even for debugging?  This one time I tried outputting 120million rows from the Database all at once, didn't work.  But buffering ( or lack of ) and flushing got it to.

Comment: 256M ? God I'm spoiled, I run with 3GB for PHP on our production server, but it has 54GB of ram ( and we do millions of rows of data, 180k searches a minute ).  The best bet is more bench marking, Try using a shutdown handler to get more information   http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: As far as I can tell, I am not outputing it anywhere.

Comment: These can be really hard to debug, because it kills execution, but as I said a shutdown handler may tell you the exact line it's failing on.

Comment: Lol, well hostgator has this limit so I use it locally as a default limit. and I dont think I should even exceed 64MB. 158 rows of 3 strings in 2 variables should be really little ! I will check out the link. Thank you!

Comment: Those examples are poor on `php.net`, in your shutdown function the main thing you need is this `function myShutdown(){ print_r(error_get_last()); }`  and then `register_shutdown_function('myShutdown')`  This will run no matter what ends execution,

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I am adding it now, but my code above looks alright and not duplicating things every time  I add an element to an array?

Comment: I get the same error exactly, no other info :(

Comment: You are duplicating things, but your replacing them with `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"] = $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"] + $format2` with the `+` note this is different then how `array_merge` behaves in some cases. ( mainly with numbered keys )

Comment: As I said try building it without the session, even just to see if the session saving is casing issues.  Performance wise it should be better every time you save something in session, it writes it to file.

Comment: What is the file that is being passed to the function?

Comment: The session file, obviously.  All session data is saved in a serialized session file on the server, typically in the `tmp` temp location.

Comment: only? this is not what sessions are usully used for.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't calling any other functions and this is the only one that makes your memory exceed? I don't really see anything wrong in this one 150 entries doesn't seem much big to me.

Comment: Just pointing out, are you storing a file really here? --> $format1 = array (........ "file" => $file); ? Is that supposed to be $fileName instead of $file? That's the only thing I could notice. (well, I really do not have any about the data you pass. I'm trying to see what could be happening)

Comment: What's interesting is that I outputted memory_get_usage()  at the start of the server request and at the end  and the results were 437888 -> 622968 so you can see the total increase in memory is only 200Kb.  Is this memory_get_usage not the right memory call?

Comment: For people asking about file, this is a filePath not file content

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if I take the the session variable out of the function and just build global variable then no memory issues. When I  copy the global variable to session then I get the issue. hmmm

Comment: Session data is serialized, but in a different way then the serialize function.  However, you could try using `serialize()` on the global data and see if it crashes. The session serialize is similar to it, but not the exact same. I am not sure if there is an easy way to replicate session serialization. If it crashes, it may be to much data to serialize or you may have some non-UTF8 stuff in there (but that is wild guess based on issues i've had with JSON )  http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: here it is `session_encode()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php  but there are some restrictions on it's use.

Comment: Yes, also you can call memory_get_peak_usage(false) within your loop and see if it goes too high at some point. Als how about setting the memory limit and go on increasing to see if you can find any clue? like ini_set('memory_limit', '600K');

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am getting there. Your suggestion is excellnet. When I do session_encode, it fails with the memory leak. That proves that the serialization of session is failing. It is weird because get memory usage and get memory peak are both reporting 0.6 Mb . How is 256M executed, I have no idea

Comment: You would/could use `strlen` on the serialized data, there is a way to convert the string length to bytes, which would give you some idea of how much data it really is, that's if you could stringafy it.

Comment: Another option is to take control of the session, `session_set_save_handler` which I think may let you serialize the data a different way,  Mostly I have used it to store in the DB ( and it's been some years for that even).  At some point you will have to convert it to a string, so less data or more memory might be the only real solution.

Comment: Alright I think I nailed it down. It was crashing with even strlen. So what I did is  I made 50calls and  I dumbed the variable that hold the data. Definitly not what I expected. It seemed that sectionIdToObjId is beoming an array of an array with every call. I guess the code above is wrong. All what I want is to have  key being id and the value be an array of (objId and filename)

Comment: I will edit the question, to point the issue, so maybe  I can get help in this so I can accept an answer about ut

Comment: Try using `array_replace` instead of `+` or `array_merge` even.  I try to avoid `+` on arrays as it acts differently in some cases.

Comment: Actually it's right here `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] =  $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id]+ array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);`  this `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] = ` adds a new array item every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine your arrays ( specifically )

```
if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id])){
    $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] =  $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id]+ array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
}else{
  ...
```

This part:

```
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] =
```

Creates a new array item that contains the previous item and the new array, the right side of the assignment.

So if `$id = 1`

```
 //iteration 1
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
 ];

 //iteration 2
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
     0 => [["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]], //old data
     1 => ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
 ];

 //iteration 3
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
    0 => [
        0 => [["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]],
        1 => ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]
     ],1 => [
        0 => [["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]],
        1 => ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]  //old data
     ]
   ],1 => ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName]  //new data
 ];
```

Or something like that, and it grows basically exponentially.  Multiply this by 158 iterations and yea, you probably wind up with a billion array items in there.

The way to fix it is simple:

```
   $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
```

So then

```
 //iteration 1
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
 ];

//iteration 2
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName], //new data
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
 ];

//iteration 3
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName], //new data
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
     ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
 ];
```

Or if `$objectId` should be unique

```
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id][$objectId] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
```

So then

```
//iteration 1 - $objectId = 34
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
    34 => ["objId" => 34, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
];

//iteration 2 - $objectId = 34 ( dupliate )
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
    34 => ["objId" => 34, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data replaces data from itteration 1
];

//iteration 3 - $objectId = 200
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [
    34 => ["objId" => 34, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
    200 => ["objId" => 200, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
];
```

**PRO-TIP** One issue you might have is you may find your keys being reset, this happens with numeric keys sometimes when serializing them. I am not sure if session serialize is prone to this.  What happens is when they conver the array to a sting they just omit the number keys, If I recall I had this issue with JSON where is saved like this (there may or may not have been some MongoDB involved ... lol):

```
    //php array
    ['data' => [1=>'foo', 64=>'bar']]

    //json data
    {"data" : [ "foo", "bar" ]}
```

So that when it un-encodes it the numbered keys get lost and you wind up with

```
    //php array
    ['data' => [0=>'foo', 1=>'bar']]
```

You can prevent this by making them a string

```
//casting using  (string)
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][(string)$id][(string)$objectId] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
```

OR (what I would do)

```
//just concatenating a string on them
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["i".$id]["j".$objectId] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
```

If you do that don't for get to check the key the same way. In the fist example ( just casting ) PHP don't care if its `1` or `"1"` it sees it the same way, loosely typed.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["i".$id])){
```

Your data will look like this

```
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["i1"] = [
    "j34" => ["objId" => 34, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
    "j200" => ["objId" => 200, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
];
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry I missed this on the first go, the way you had it you  wind up with this:

```
//iteration 1 - $id was not set
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] = ["objId" => 1, "fileName" => $fileName];

//iteration 2 - $id is now set ( we overwrite the first pass ) so we lost ogjId = 1
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] = [
    ["objId" => 5, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data replaces data from itteration 1
];

//iteration 3 
$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] = [
    ["objId" => 5, "fileName" => $fileName], //new data
    ["objId" => 10, "fileName" => $fileName] //new data
];
```

Also when accessing this,

on the first iteration you have one array so `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"]["objId"]` is accessible

```
 foreach($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] as $key=>$var )
      //on first iteration key = objId, value = 1
```

on the second iteration you have nested array so  `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"][0]["objId"]` is accessible  notice the extra `[0]` in there.

```
 foreach($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] as $key=>$var )
      //on first iteration key = 0, value = ['objId' => 5, ... ]
```

This can cause issues where that data is not structured the way you want, when looping you would have individual items in the first case, but the second case would give you an entire array.  So you are dealing with 2 structures that way.

I would just assume that it will have more then one item. then it will be like the second case all the time, nested arrays.

```
  if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][(string)$id])){
      //define our variable as an empty array
      $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][(string)$id] = [];
  }

  //add all day long
  $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][(string)$id][] = ["objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName];
```

Then you get this:

```
  $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] =[
        ["objId"=>1 ...]
  ];

 //instead of 
 $_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"]["1"] = ["objId"=>1 ...];
```

hope that makes sense.

One last thing `PHP5.4` added short array syntax so instead of doing

```
 $a = array(...);
```

We can just do

```
 $a = [ ... ];
```

Now, So if you see me doing that, that is all it is. Us PHP guys are lazy, I mean efficient.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix this ?I come from Java background and this basic operation is confusing the earth out of me

Comment: Depends how it should look after a few alterations, is that new data to be added to this or merged to it.  I guess merged

Comment: `I come from Java background` - I am truly sorry, I feel for you.  Java is to verbose for me.

Comment: Well it starts with empty variable and every call to the method should basically handle the 3 paramters. Meanhing if it is the same ID then it will add an array item to that ID. If it is new ID, then it creates new Id pointing to an array of one item. If you know java , it is  Hashmap of ArrayList of Hashmaps

Comment: Ohhh Thank you so much for the fix. I wish there is away I can send you bonus points for the help. One last thing, in your example above, if ID 2 is received, will the above statmenet handles it or should I check if ID2 exists before adding it?

Comment: You only have to check if you try to add something to a key that doesn't exist, like this  say `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1]` dosen't exist if you try to add `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1][34] = [...]` when `1` is undefined it's not gonna like it.  But you can add `$_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][1] = [...]` just fine.  I guess it would be the parent key.

Comment: It's like you can do `$foo[1] = 1;` but you can't do `$foo[1] += 1` or `++$foo[1]` because PHP has to do a read of `$foo[1]` before the assignment (for incrementing, it has to get the previous value), it's the read that blows up, not the assignment.  In the first just setting it to `1` PHP don't care what the old value was.

Comment: @Snake - make sure to read what I wrote about the numeric keys, as you come from JAVA that will be a very foreign concept to you.  Number keys are not like string keys,  one is just an array the other is a hashmap.  I don't know if it will be an issue, but after saving it and on a next request you can check with `print_r($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"])` or `var_dump(..)` or `var_export(..)` sometime it helps to do `echo "<pre>"` to keep the whitespacing.  None of that `system.out.println()` junk here.

Comment: You are the best. Very helpful tips offcourse especially about the id numbers being dropped during serialization!. Wow. I guess php is not as trivial as I thought ( at least for now)

Comment: PHP is awsome, I might be a bit biased as I been doing it like 7 years, and I had to do some Java a year or so ago ... so I feal you.  Java is to hard to refactor code, all that defining of return values and exceptions..  PHP is liberating.

Comment: Does this look about right to you  (objectId has chars in it) :    if(isset($_tempSessionB[$id])){
  $_tempSessionB[(string)$id][] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
 }else{
  $_tempSessionB[(string)$id] =  array("objId" => $objectId, "fileName" => $fileName);
 }

Comment: _tempSessionB is just the same variable (my  debug global one)

Comment: Yes and no, see you will lose the stuff you put in the `else` as you overwrite it.  like this `$a["1"] = ['foo']` then the next time `$a["1"] = [["bar"]]`.  I'll do an update.

Comment: Aha.. hmm but you are using the + in your new update and made the statement similar to what I had the very first time that resulted in duplicates. No?Am I not reading it right?

Comment: Yea I fixed it, copy and paste error.  But I am done now.  You get what I am saying about having the structure change. That's the important bit.  We just do isset to define a default for that variable, because you are adding to it PHP will probably issue a warning for undefined offset, if you don't.

Comment: Thank you. Yes  I get what you mean. I am trying things as you are updating :) . The last update you had, is always giving one item array for each id.hmmm

Comment: It seems it is overwriting it is keeping track of the last item added only

Comment: Surprisngly, If I comment out the isset statemnt along with its code,  everything is populated correctly!!

Comment: Instead of `if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][$id])){` try `if(isset($_SESSION["sectionIdToObjId"][(string)$id])){`  It may be thinking it is never set then we reset the array every time in that case.

Comment: Also if you have display errors off, you wont see the warnings,  `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1)` before any code.

Comment: Same issue. I guess I dont need the isset since the code  works with population for new ID. But I am now curious to know why it is overwriting as it makes sense what you have